# Ubuntu boots to start screen - Bootable USB fails

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair

My Ubuntu 20.04 now only boots to the start screen shown below and hangs there.  I want to get to a terminal but I cannot seem to make that happen.  I have tried all of the restart/key combinations like shift, exc, F 1-12. Nothing seems to work - I just get to the same screen. Additionally, I have created a 20.04 bootable flash drive using another Ubuntu computer.  Similarly, there are no F keys that will boot to the flash drive.

Just prior to this happening I was trying to open an image file in GIMP.  Gimp said it could not access the resource (the image file on the second SSHD).  Thinking there was some path or permissions issue I tried to move the image to my home folder and got a 'not enough memory' error.  Thinking I had run out of memory I tried to purged the trash folder as there was a heap of stuff in there.  I got a message that I did not have permissions to delete some items in trash.

I was logged in as my regular account and there are no other user accounts on this computer.  In response I turned off the computer.  On restart on got the screen shown below.

How do I get to the terminal?

[image]